# SPLongOperation End() redirect issue

Tags: 2013, splongoperation

I am using `SPLongOperation` while creating a sub-site using template. The issue I am facing is when sub-site is created and I redirect using `SPLongOperation.End()` I am getting below error:

> Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.

Here is my code sample:

```
try{    
using (SPLongOperation lo = new SPLongOperation(Page)) 
       {
          lo.Begin();
          // Create Sub-site using template
          lo.End(sub-site URL);// here it throws error
       }
}
catch(exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

When I search this error, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041482/unable-to-evaluate-expression-because-the-code-is-optimized-or-a-native-frame-is) link which suggest we need to pass `false` parameter while redirect. But I am not able to pass this in `SPLongOperation`.

If anyone can suggest how can I solve this? Thanks in Advance.